# Edge thickness of the faces in a surface plot

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

Is it possible to change the drawing thickness of the edges of the faces in a surface plot in `PGFplots`?

For example, in the minimum working example

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot3[surf,faceted color=black] {x+y};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

, how do I change the drawing thickness of the black edges of the faces?

[image]

Comment: Just to be sure, do you want to increase the thicknes only for the four edges of the whole plot or do you want to change the thickness for the complete set of rules (including the inner ones)?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Your solution was the one I was looking for. I meant the drawing thickness of each edge of each face (or element) in the complete surface plot. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps I misunderstand the question? You can use the `line width` option:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot3[surf,faceted color=black] {x+y};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}\qquad
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot3[surf,faceted color=black,line width=0.01pt] {x+y};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```